# how to increment column value by 1 every time user fails to login in python pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

This is my modal class that will be used to track the number of time user tries to login. Every time user fails to login I would like to increment attempt column fields by 1. what is the best way to do it.

I am trying to do this for now but not working and throwing me differnt types error.
**Code to get the attempt column value with based on email and status=success which happens after success login** As the attempt column is incremented by 1 every time user fails to login. From that am fetching the number of attempts.

```
@classmethod
def getAttemptCount(cls,email):
    return DBSession.query(Logs.attempt).filter(and_(Logs.email==email,Logs.status=='success')).all()
```

**Here is the table definition**

```
from .meta import Base
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Index,
    Integer,
    Text,
    Unicode
    )


class Logs(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'logs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Unicode(255),nullable=False)
    status=Column(Text,default='error')
    attempt=Column(Integer,default=0)
```

What is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have on my login view, might give you an idea on how to do it.

```
@view_config(route_name="login", request_method="POST", renderer="app:templates/app/login.mak")
def login_(request):
email = request.params.get('email')
password = request.params.get('password')
if form.validate(): #valid fields i.e. not empty
    try:
       user = DBSession.query(User).filter_by(email=email).one()
    except NoResultFound:
       return #no user found
    if len(user):
      if user.attempt > 10:
        return #show captcha or something    
      if not user.check(password):
        user.attempt +=1
        return #redirect or return False
      headers = remember(request, user.id)
      user.attempt = 0 #could reset the attempt count if login successful
      return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('dashboard'), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Doesn't this introduce a race condition at `user.attempt += 1`? You want to add 1 to the value currently stored in the database, not what your local object has stored. If this is handling more than one request at a time, you could have two login attempts, but counter end up only incremented up one. Maybe user.attempt = User.attempt + 1?